# Angular - Showing a message if a user enters the wrong login details

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to show a message if a user has entered a password in the wrong way.

The below function returns a error when the user enters the details to login wrong:

```
     scope.emailLogin = function () {
        AuthService.emailLogin(scope.credentials)
        .then(function () {
            // Redirect
            AssessmentService.loadAssessmentCache();
            state.go('app.tab.assessments');
        },
        function (err) {
            console.error(JSON.stringify(err));
            scope.validationError = true;
        });
    };
```

In the html I was trying to show the message by doing an ng-show if the validationError becomes true as you can see below:

```
<p ng-show="validationError">Incorrect email or password</p>
```

To conclude:
I just want to show a message when the fucntion returns as an error

This is what the console log, logs:

```
modules.js:870 {"data":"Incorrect email or password","status":500,"config":{"method":"PUT","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"auth":false,"handlers":[null],"url":"http://localhost:8080/api/authcallbacks/local","headers":{"x-client-type":"figr","Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"},"data":{"email":"user1@test.co","password":"123123"}},"statusText":"Internal Server Error"}
```

Comment: Does the backend send an error when the credentials are wrong? Or does it simply send some data?

Comment: ng-if is better than ng-show

Comment: I'll update the question with what the err returns

Comment: Have you seen the logged error in your console? let's see first if the error callback is hit.

Comment: Just updated my answer with the errorconsole log message

Comment: is your emailLogin function and p tag within the same ng-controller ?

Comment: Yeah they are within the same state

Comment: and does AuthService.emailLogin function have a $http call or a $.ajax ?

Comment: What do you see when you do `<pre>{{ validationError | json }}</pre>`?

Comment: You're mission `$` in your `$scope`... is this a linking function of a directive of a controller?

Comment: nah its being called.. we have an odd coding convention where we remove the $ don't ask me why

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like this should be working, you may want to check that

`<p ng-show="validationError">Incorrect email or password</p>`

is in the proper ng-controller scope.

Answer (score 0):

Stupidly... it was Ionic..I had to do an Ionic serve and my code worked fine... Sorry for wasting your time guys